# Django Creating form with a list

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a set of choices

```
choices1=(('mahi'),('is'),('awesome'))
```

I want to create a dropdown form menu to select those options. How would I do so?

I have tried

`title1 = forms.CharField(max_length=2, choices=choices1)` but get an error too many values to unpack.

What should I do?

Comment: You are only give name for option values in your drop down not values. it should be tuple of tuple choices1=(('mahi', 'mahi'),('is', 'is'),('awesome', 'awesome')). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860606/how-to-build-a-select-box-with-a-list-of-countries-for-a-form-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ChoiceField which renders by default select field

```
title1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices1)
```

And fix your choices to

```
(('mahi', 'mahi'),('is', 'is'),('awesome', 'awesome'))
```

It should be tuples

Comment: Is there a quick way to make it tuples? I am asking because in the original scenario, there are over a 100 of choices and I can't manually fix all the choices.

Comment: i just did zip (choices1,choices1). I feel like it should work now